# JMX: MaxFileDescriptorCount and OpenFileDescriptorCount

Tags: java, linux, jmx

We want to monitor the number of open file descriptors in our Tomcat app server.  I stumbled across the MaxFileDescriptorCount and OpenFileDescriptorCount attributes of the java.lang OperatingSystem MBean.  There doesn't seem to be a lot of information on these attributes, at least from what I can Google for.

My questions are:

- Is it safe to use these attributes for monitoring? In other words, can the values for these attributes be trusted?
- When looking at OpenFileDescriptorCount over JConsole, the value is "Unavailable".  Can anybody explain why this is the case?

I know that there is the lsof command for Linux, but it would be nice if we can use some existing JMX-enabled monitoring tools to monitor these values.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I can't answer your first question because I also did not find useful information concerning this yet.
Regarding your second question: a potential cause for the value being "Unavailable" might be that the operating system is not unix. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/mxbeans.html